# Byte Order Mark generating a file using Mono in Ubuntu

Tags: java, encoding, ubuntu, mono

My .NET utility AjGenesis is a code generation tool. The compiled binaries runs without glitches under Ubuntu 10.x, and Mono. But I have a problem: generating a java text file (a normal text file for my tool) it generates Byte Order Mark at the beginning of each file. I'm using System.Text.Encoding.Default: in Windows, all OK, in Ubuntu, the Byte Order Mark are three bytes, indicating UTF8, I guess.

This difference is a problem, when I want to compile the generate .java files using ant, or javac, the BOMs generate errors. Then:

- What encoding to use in Ubuntu/Mono so the generated files could be processed by javac?
- I tried javac -encoding UTF8 without success, any clues? My guess: it's not for skip BOMs.
- I tried System.Text.Encoding.ASCII. But my generated files have non ASCII files (Spanish accented letters). If I change the encoding, the BOMs are added, and javac refuses the files. Any suggestion?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Encoding.Default`. Why make your output platform specific? Use UTF-8 - and if you have to use UTF-8 without a BOM, you can do that with:

```
Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```

To be honest though, I'm surprised javac fails. You say you've tried it "without success" - what was the result?

Comment: Sorry the delay. Now is workings, thanks!

javac failed because the extra byte was rejected by the compiler as invalid in source code. It read them as an extra character.

Answer (score 1):

Try instantiating System.Text.UTF8Encoding and supplying a parameter value that doesn't include BOMs. You may read about this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2.aspx